# store.getat undefined - but store is loaded and has data

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

i am calling the `init` function after the `initComponent` has finished and form is active.

To test I set it up like this:

```
console.log(this.store);
console.log(this.store.getAt(0));
```

The first one shows the store - and store has data.
Second one returns undefined.

Why is that so? If the first `console.log` shows the data - it should already be available also for the second one.

```
   init: function() {
     var rec = this.store.getAt(0);
     this.setValues(rec);
     this.id = rec.id;
   }
```

Comment: The data is not there yet... if after the first console.log you write some code that throws an error, you will see that the data will disappear. Something like `console.log(this.store); console.log(test.test());` this should throw a Reference Error saying that test is not defined and your store will still be empty.

Comment: how come the first logged object has data in it then - i can browse through the nodes and see the data itself?

Comment: I know you can browse the object and your console.log shows the data there, but its not actually there. The only way to ensure the data is there is to use callbacks like toree pointed out.

Comment: Just as quick note, sometimes you will also NOT see some information that should be available there. ExtJS can get tricky sometimes, you will have to get used to it. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wait for the load event on the store before accessing it's data. I Guess that the console is quite smart, updating content when object is changing.

```
init: function(){
    this.store.on('load', function(){
        var rec = this.store.getAt(0);
        this.setValues(rec);
        this.id = rec.id;
    }, this);
}
```